# Numpy Matrix: Malformed String

Tags: python, string, numpy, matrix

I get the following error `ValueError: malformed string` when using the following code:

```
import numpy 
l=[]
for x in [0.0,1.0]:
    for y in [0.0,1.0]:
        for z in [0.0,1.0]:
            if x+y+z ==1:
                print x
                pr_matrix = numpy.matrix('x ; y ; z')
                l.append(pr_matrix)
```

It seems to me that the numpy.matrix function is unable to understand that x,y,z are of type float and not of type string.
I say so because the following works fine.

```
matrix = np.matrix('1 2 2;2 3 1')
```

Comment: in no way is `np.matrix('1 2 2;2 3 1')` the same as `numpy.matrix('x ; y ; z')`, that's why one works and the other doesn't

Comment: Pls fix your indentation, and f=define `l`

Comment: @Adelin not the same in what sense, if you are referring to the number of arguments given, each ";" defines a column.

Comment: Do you mean to do something like `numpy.matrix(str(x) + ' ; ' + str(y) + ' ; ' + str(z))` to create the matrix dynamically?

Comment: I know. I wanted to give you some hints but yeah, as OptimusCrime said, when you use `'x ; y ; z'` in a string, it's simply a character, not a variable as you are probably expecting

Comment: @OptimusCrime no, this is Invalid Syntax. The ';' is used to denote the columns of the matrix, using ' ' before and after it will not work, since the function np.matrix will not be able to understand the columns.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. My code will, in the first iteration of the loops, result in the following code: `numpy.matrix('0.0 ; 0.0 ; 1.0')`. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @OptimusCrime you are rightm it worked. Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use numpy.matrix. It's deprecated and will be removed in the future NumPy releases. Instead you can use a simple comprehension

```
import itertools, numpy as np
arr=np.array([[[x],[y],[z]] for x,y,z in itertools.product(*[[1,0]]*3) if x+y+z==1])[:,:,0]
```

Here, `itertools.product` is creating the cartesian product `[0, 1]x[0, 1]x[0, 1]` which is what you do with 3 nested loops. To give this argument to the `itertools.product` we basically first create three copies of `[0,1]` in an iterable.

Then with a star argument (`*`) before this iterable, we instruct to interpret the elements of this iterable as separate arguments so we get three distinct arguments. This produces the cartesian product

```
[(1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0)]
```

let's call this `A`. Then we do a list comprehension over A. For each element in `A` which is a 3-tuple `x,y,z` we form a column and add it to the list created by the list comprehension if their sum is 1.

The result is then

```
[[[1], [0], [0]], [[0], [1], [0]], [[0], [0], [1]]]
```

and then an NumPy array is created but notice it is 3D. so we take the relevant part with a slice. You can also use `np.squeeze` for this.

Comment: I think your answer, while helpful, would be more valuable in the language OP understands (i.e. without one liners(

Comment: @Adelin Hmm, I don't know which part might be confusing. Care to elaborate?

Comment: OP didn’t even know about concatenation of variables with strings, let alone other more somewhat advanced topics

Comment: @Adelin Better?

Comment: Awesome :) too bad I can only upvote once (which I did even before the edit)